# Trouble w. phpmyadmin install

Tags: php, mbstring

I have done everything that I should [I think] to install phpmyadmin but then when I try to access it I always get this error message : "Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in C:\Apache\htdocs\phpMyAdmin\phpMyAdmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc on line 177"

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable mbstring. In your php.ini, uncomment

```
extension=php_mbstring.dll
```

by removing `;` in front of it, then restart Apache.

Comment: weoll I just now tried to do what you suggested. [I even enabled other extensions in the massive php.ini file] But I am afraid that it didn't help!! I have seen many youtube tutorials on how to install phpmyadmin but I am still stuck with this same error msg.

Comment: Do you have this extension on your system?

Comment: Are you sure you're editing the correct php.ini? On some systems, there are several and you might be changing the wrong one. Check the output of `phpinfo()` for the correct file location.